# Jupyter Notebook's auto completion feature not available?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-10, jupyter, anaconda3

Anaconda3 was installed. But no auto-completion is available for Jupiter Notebook when started from the command line. But Auto-completion becomes available if the Jupyter Notebook is started from the Start menu by clicking on "Jupyter Notebook", which is inside the Anaconda folder in the start menu.

For the following code, pressing the TAB key after the dot doesn't help. The auto-complete drop-down list doesn't open.

```
import numpy as np
np.
```

What would be the cause for Jupyter Notebook to not display code Auto-Completion?